# TSP with max node and time limit

Tags: time, max, nodes, cplex, traveling-salesman

I have to creat a CPLEX model to the GTSP, I have to maximize the visits with a time limit and some obligation visits! 
Is there a general modeling for this? If not, can anyone help me with this and I will send him my code to catch the error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question seems unclear to me. If your question is about the algorithm, please try asking a question on [SE](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com), if its about equations or the mathematical modeling you can try [ComputerScience](http://cs.stackexchange.com) or even [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com). Otherwise, please include your code (or at least code fragments) to show what you've tried so far to clarify your question.

Comment: @ventiseis How can I contact you ?

Comment: I've reviewed your question because it was in triage, not because I'm a an `cplex` expert. I'm afraid I can't help you with your problem, but perhaps with finding answers from other users. Have you tried [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cplex+tsp) answers for your problem? Perhaps they contain not the exact solution which you're looking for, but hints for your solution. It would certainly help other users if you elaborate your question a little more - particulary because this is a complex problem.  Finally, if you want to contact me, write a comment here.

Comment: I am considered to be a CPLEX expert (probably, just 20+ years experience). I suggest you look at the standard CPLEX examples, and then look online for further examples and models. You are unlikely to find a pre-existing model for a specific problem variation, but can probably take a similar problem's model and add the necessary extensions and/or additional constraints. Be aware that straightforward models of TSPs and similar problems *will* break down for problems that are bigger than quite small sizes. To solve big TSPs and related problems is really hard.